# Django Celery task error while invoked in Post request

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, celery

I have a below task to run notifications asynchronously

```
@shared_task(name="notifications_task")
def notifications_task(activity_type,obj=None, target=None):
    dispatch_notification_activity(activity_type,obj, target)
```

In the views,py in a post request, I am calling this notfications_task as below

```
 notifications_task.delay(UpdateTypeEnum.STOCK_WATCHED, obj=user, target=instance)
```

The Function dispatch_notification_activity takes care of the push notifications, since it takes more Time , I am running it asynchronously

getting the below error while calling the notifications_task :     kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type UpdateTypeEnum is not JSON serializable

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\apps\stock_watchlist\views.py", line 42, in post
    notifications_task.delay(UpdateTypeEnum.STOCK_WATCHED, obj=user, target=instance)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 421, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\task.py", line 561, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 718, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\amqp.py", line 538, in send_task_message
    ret = producer.publish(
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 164, in publish
    body, content_type, content_encoding = self._prepare(
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 249, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "C:\Users\Fleetstudio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 53, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\exceptions.py", line 21, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 49, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\json.py", line 65, in dumps
    return _dumps(s, cls=cls or _default_encoder,
  File "C:\Users\Fleetstudio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Users\Fleetstudio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Fleetstudio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "E:\stocktalk-api-platform\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\json.py", line 55, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "C:\Users\Fleetstudio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type UpdateTypeEnum is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Your task arguments (by default) must be json-serializable, as the error suggest. Neither enum values, nor the User object are. You can set the serializer to pickle to support that, but it's not encouraged

Comment: I am quite new to DRF, can you help me to rectify it ?? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alexandr pointed out, task arguments must be JSON serializable. You can pass user and target id, and enum value, and then serialize them inside the task, something like this:

```py
notifications_task.delay(UpdateTypeEnum.STOCK_WATCHED.value, obj_id=user.id, target_id=instance.id)
```

And inside the task:

```py
@shared_task(name="notifications_task")
def notifications_task(activity_type_val, obj_id=None, target_id=None):
    # Get activity type enum object from value
    activity_type = UpdateTypeEnum(activity_type_val)
    # Get object by id
    obj = YourUserModel.objects.get(id=obj_id)
    # Get target by id
    target = YourTargetModel.objects.get(id=target_id)
    # Now call yout method
    dispatch_notification_activity(activity_type, obj, target)
```

Comment: As the error says, you passed *Object of type UpdateTypeEnum*. Note that I passed `UpdateTypeEnum.STOCK_VATCHED.value`, which is integer (I guess, if UpdateTypeEnum is IntEnum).  Also, you have to restart celery worker after making changes for them to be really applied.

Comment: It works now , initially I missed this part  (UpdateTypeEnum.STOCK_WATCHED.value, obj_id=user.id, target_id=instance.id), Thanks so much for your help, please let me know from which part of the log you identified this issue. So in feature, I can also also detect this

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it. From the last line, where it says object is not json serializable, since Celery sends/recevies messages to/from a broker in a json format, using different api for different broker. Just like a basic rest api, you cannot send objects instances, there has to be a serializer in between.